# PDO consulta MySQL arroja error 500

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy tratando de mostrar el valor de una consulta parametrizada  en `PHP` con `PDO` pero me arroja el error 500. Realicé el cambio metiendo un valor en la consulta y quitando la parametrización. Con eso funcionó, pero no consigo que funcione con el parámetro, ¿Qué error estoy cometiendo? Este es mi archivo `php`:

```
<?php
  //datos de ingreso
  try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=host; dbname=host", "host", "host");
    $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error: no se ha podido establecer la conexión: " . $e -> getMessage());
  }

  //consulta parametrizada:
  //$id = $_GET["id"];
  //$sql = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT cantidad FROM cartuchos WHERE idCartucho = :id");
  //$sql -> bind_param(':id', $id); //aquí hago la parametrización pero no me ha funcionado

  //consulta sin parámetros, funciona:
  $id = 1;
  $sql = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT cantidad FROM cartuchos WHERE idCartucho = 1");
  $sql -> execute();

  if(!$sql){
    echo 'Error al ejecutar la consulta.';
  } else{
    // $results = $sql -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // echo json_encode($results);
    echo $sql->fetchColumn();
  }
?>
```

Y así es como lo mando en la url:

```
midominio.com/carpeta/consulta.php?id=1
```

Repito, el problema solo se provoca al usar la parametrización

Comment: Pues, el error es: `Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found` Pero insisto, este error solo sucede si parametrizo la consulta. La consulta sin el parámetro, funciona bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes una confusión entre el controlador Mysqli y PDO.
En Mysql usar [bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), en PDO [bindParam()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cantidad FROM cartuchos WHERE idCartucho=:id");
$sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
$sql->execute();
// ...
```